# Image is getting stretched as per UITableView width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

Below is how I have structure.

```
UITableView (304px)
    - UIImageView (as seperator line) (I want this to be 288px) but it stretched to 304 px.
    - UITableViewCell (304 px)
        - UIImageView (background for cell) (288px)
        - Label 1 for text display
        - Label 2 for text display
```

I am stretching UITableView just to take scrollbar at the end of yellow part as shown in image.

[image]

Everything works perfect except the separator line.

Even if I put width as 288 and click on somewhere else and come back to see width of UIImageView, it get changed to 304 (which is UITableView width) automatically.

Any idea why this is happening and how to make separator line of 288 px only.

**Note**

The separator line is above UITableViewCell. Not inside UITableViewCell

**The separator line that I am talking about is the first line in above image.**

---

### Edit 1

I also tried with below code, but still its stretched to 304px.

```
UIImageView *mySep = (UIImageView*)[mainTableView viewWithTag:56565656];
[mySep setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,288,2)];
```

---

### Edit 2

I have uploaded sample project at [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7f30ludwzqvj09e/TestScroll.zip).

Please remove the line `[mySep release];` from `- (void)scrollingFinish {`. Else app gets crashed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed.

Nice cheat I can say. I added UIView and put separator line inside UIView. Set UIView background color to clearColor and let UIView stretch as much as he want.

```
UITableView (304px)
    - UIView (have width as 304px OR 288px, but background color will be clearColor. This is very important).
        - UIImageView (as seperator line) (This will be 288px).
    - UITableViewCell (304 px)
        - UIImageView (background for cell) (288px)
        - Label 1 for text display
- Label 2 for text display
```

So what will happen is UIView will get stretch, but image will be of 288px only. As we have UIView background color as clearColor, we cannot see the stretched view.

Answer (score 3):

I solved your problem. In table view you can add only 2 sub views like footer and header. one is above cell another is below. these views width are equal to UITableview width. So when you do something like that. Not just add the UIImageview first add UIView and set its frame then add your UIImage view here is the fixed sample project given by -Fahim Parkar

[Fixed Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2qw3liwb4d8qw8u/TestScroll.zip)

Comment: Thanks.. But did you changed the font of label? I am getting error `The document "MainStoryboard.storyboard" could not be opened. Could not read archive.`

Comment: or can you send me screenshot of IB?

Comment: I found a solution... i Fixed my way

Comment: I use xCode5 thats why you couldnt. Solution was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your cell size?

Do you create your cell object with code or using Storyboard?

Try to resize your imageview in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
UIImageView *seperator = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:_sepTag];
[seperator setFrame:CGRectMake(8,seperator.frame.origin.y,288,seperator.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: its not in cell... cell image is perfect... above cell I am showing one separator line... the problem is there...

Comment: I also tried with your code in some way, but still its same error

Comment: Do you set an image? Or do you use backgroud color

Comment: I will be waiting. or you can send me via email.

Comment: what I noticed is at first it makes as 288 width, but when I scroll, it again goes to 304.

Comment: How do you add the seperator?

Comment: try [[view layer] setMaskToBounds:YES]; does x origin change?

Comment: I have uploaded sample project at https://www.dropbox.com/s/7f30ludwzqvj09e/TestScroll.zip Please see and let me know your findings...

Answer (score 0):

I know its very old post and i was having same problem too but i rectified it by fixing the height of image view in auto layout.

hope that helps.